# How to add unnumbered lines in an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, line-numbering

I am typesetting algorithms with the *algorithm* package, and I would like to add unnumbered lines in them. 
Is there a way to create a `\State*` command, the same way there is an `equation*` environment?

Here is an example of algorithm. I would like the `\State {}` line to be unnumbered, and therefore `\State Step 3.` to be number 3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A title.} 
\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
\State Step 1.
\State Step 2. 
\State {}
\State Step 3.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To add input and output before MyProcedure a possibility is to add the text before \begin{algorithmic} with starred hspace \hspace*{}(see 6.3.3 Horizontal Space) and the indentation \algorithmicindent (see 4.1 Blocks and loops). 

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355937/how-to-add-input-and-output-before-algorithm-procedure

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By virtue of the fact that you are using `algpseudocode`, it looks like you are actually using the [`algorithmicx` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/).  From page 4 of its [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf), it looks like you want the `\Statex` command.

If for some reason that doesn't work, a solution can be nastily hacked by forcing suppression of the line number:

```
\def\NoNumber#1{{\def\alglinenumber##1{}\State #1}\addtocounter{ALG@line}{-1}}
```

You can then use `\NoNumber` like `\State`:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A title.} 
\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
\State Step 1.
\State Step 2. 
\NoNumber{This line will not have a number!}
\State Step 3.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. It seems I didn't look in the right manual... Thanks!

Comment: This solution does not work in case I want to put `\NoNumber` in the first line of the pseudocode, or just after `\EndIf`. But `\Statex` works perfectly.