# Unnumbered lines in algorithm

Tags: algorithms, line-numbering, algorithmic

My question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11269/11860), I need to skip number for some lines of the algorithm. However the solution from that question does not work for me.
How can I disable numbers for some lines using the `algorithmic` package?

This is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\usepackage{algorithm} 

\def\NoNumber#1{{\def\alglinenumber##1{}\State #1}\addtocounter{ALG@line}{-1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE Compute $Pr(X_i < x)$ and $Pr(x < X_i)$ for all $i = 1, \dots, M$ and
\FOR {$i = 1, \dots, n$}
\STATE with a number
\NoNumber{ without number}
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The way `algorithmic` numbers lines makes it very difficult to leave off a line.

Comment: @msh I added a final remark to my answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One option would be to use the more versatile [`algorithmicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package, with its `algcompatible` format (allowing you to use `algorithmic` syntax); you can use  `\STATEx` for unnumbered lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algcompatible}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\IF{some condition is true}
\STATE do some processing
\ELSIF{some other condition is true}
\STATEx do some different processing
\ELSIF{some even more bizarre condition is met}
\STATEx do something else
\ELSE
\STATE do the default actions
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the use of `algcompatible` was suggested only if you already have your algorithms written using the `algorithmic` syntax and want to switch to `algorithmicx` without major traumatism; if you are just starting to write your algorithms, then use the `algpseudocode` format instead from the beginning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\If{some condition is true}
\State do some processing
\ElsIf{some other condition is true}
\Statex do some different processing
\ElsIf{some even more bizarre condition is met}
\Statex do something else
\Else
\State do the default actions
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer below is far more simple

Answer (score 6):

Add an empty line for the line break and then just write whatever you want in the next line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\usepackage{algorithm} 

\def\NoNumber#1{{\def\alglinenumber##1{}\State #1}\addtocounter{ALG@line}{-1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE Compute $Pr(X_i < x)$ and $Pr(x < X_i)$ for all $i = 1, \dots, M$ and
\FOR {$i = 1, \dots, n$}
\STATE with a number

without number
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is as simple as efficient !